# Select distinct only on one column with Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am getting mad for selecting only one disctint column over a set of column

Let's say I have this query: `SELECT A, B, C, D FROM TABLE WHERE A = 1`

And this is the output

```
A B C D
1 2 8 5
1 2 2 5
1 2 3 5
```

But I would like something like this:

```
A B C D
1 2 8 5
```

How could I achieve this?

Thanks to all!

Comment: How do you know you want 8 in the 3rd column? Do you really want the highest value (i.e. aggregate and group-by), or some other rule? And what if the 2nd or 4th columns also have different values, for a different A?

Comment: Why do you think "8" is "distinct" value for column "C"?

Comment: If you have several rows with `A = 1`, which one should be selected? Or are you OK with just selecting "one of them, doesn't matter which one"?

Comment: Yes sorry, I want the highest number, I would to like to get a single row with the highest number in the C column. A must be distinct, I tried with MAX but without success

Comment: Edit the question to show what you tried with max, and why it didn't work - wrong result, or error? Are C and D always distinct for each A, and if not do you want the highest value from each column? Or the row that has the highest C?

Comment: The highest value doesn't imply uniqueness.

Comment: SELECT A, B, MAX(C), D FROM TABLE WHERE A = 1 but it says is not a single group by function

Comment: `SELECT A, B, MAX(C), D FROM TABLE WHERE A = 1 group by A, B, D`

Comment: @GurwinderSingh - that does not solve the OP's problem, what if you have more than one `(A, B, D)` group where `A = 1`?

Comment: @mathguy Yea. I was just correcting his query. :P

Comment: @Chrix1387 - The requirement is still not complete. What if you have two rows with `A = 1` and the same highest value of `C` - for example, `1, 2, 8, 5` and `1, 4, 8, 3`? Which one to choose?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to order the results by column C descending and then just take the first row:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT A, B, C, D
    FROM TABLE_NAME
    WHERE A = 1
    ORDER BY C DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

---

Comment: This is still guessing, right? The requirement didn't say "other than `A=1` and `C` maximized, the choice of `B` and `D` can be random."

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
    A, B, max(C) C, D
From table_name 
Group by A, B, D
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a results with highest number in C try below query
SELECT A,B,C,D FROM table WHERE A=1 AND C IN(SELECT MAX(C) FROM table);